# Getting javax.media.NoProcessorException

Tags: java, jmf

Following is the code from my audio, video recording project. The audio file is getting created but while creating video file "testVideo.mov" I am getting "javax.media.NoProcessorException: Cannot find a Processor" exception.

```
ImageDataSource ids = new ImageDataSource(width, height, frameRate);
    Processor p;

    try 
    {
        UFBScrRecLogs.write("- create processor for the image datasource ...");
        p = Manager.createProcessor(ids);
    } catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
```

when I am executing this code in eclipse it is working fine but when I make windows installer of the application  and ran this application after installing it then I am getting above error.

I am not getting why it is running in eclipse environment but not as windows application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Actually it was jmf jar problem. I was using a old jmf jar now I used latest jmf jar and exception is not coming.

Answer (score 0):

Might be a classpath problem. Maybe the windows environment does not provide a quicktime processor. Check the eclipse build path as well as the classpath on the windows machine for any differences in java version (different standard libs) and other libraries.

Plus check the classpath settings of your application.